# visual studio c++ /utf-8 странное поведение std::string

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-8, c++20

Я включил параметр `/utf-8` в `visual studio`, сохранил файл в `UTF-8(with BOM)` и написал следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) noexcept
{
    std::cout << std::string("привет мир!").size();
}
```

Как результат я получил число 20. Я понимаю почему это произошло, но как это исправить?

Comment: ¿Что значит "исправить"? Исправлять надо, когда что-то идет не так.

Comment: @user7860670 мне надо чтобы метод возвращал 11

Comment: `std::wstring(L"привет мир!").size();` - устроит?

Comment: @Harry нет, используя utf-8 нельзя такое провернуть?

Comment: В при использовании utf8 этот метод должен возвращать 20. Если вам надо посчитать длину по-другому (например вычисляя количество символов или количество глифов), то следует воспользоваться библиотекой ICU.

Comment: что вы делаете?! это временный объект. Значение выражения удаляется сразу после скобок. А метод sizer () будет ссилатся на удаленный объект.

Comment: @ТарасПрогер Ничего подобно, объект будет еще живым.

Comment: хорошо. спасибки. не професионал я

Comment: @ТарасПрогер Он удаляется после `;`. http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4.sentence-3

Comment: проблема в том, что для юникодных строк понятие длины немного неочевидно. Что именно считать длиной - количество code points, количество глифов. Или что нибудь ещё.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться фасетом [`std::codecvt<char32_t, char8_t, std::mbstate_t>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) для преобразования `UTF-8` в [`UTF-32`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32). Это позволит подсчитать количество кодовых точек юникода в строке. [Примерно так](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f560a9ee3f5f946). Впрочем нужно иметь ввиду, что некоторые символы могут кодироваться как одной кодовой точкой, так и несколькими. Например, буква `Й` имеет свою отдельную кодовую точку, но также может быть получена комбинацией буквы `И` и  диакритического знака.

Comment: думаю, правильно говорить "видимые символы". А некоторые символы могут кодироваться с помощью 6 кодовых точек.

Comment: За Visual Studio, особенно без указания версии, не скажу, но по C++20 оператор `std::cout << std::wstring(L"привет мир!").size() << ' ' << sizeof(U"привет мир!")/sizeof(U"") - 1 << '\n';` напечатает `11 11`.

Comment: @KoVadim, как бы и для ASCII `"A\b_"` это символ _A_ с подчёркиванием, который занимает одно знакоместо, но число символов это результаты: метода `size()` для `std::wstring`, либо `wcslen()`, либо `sizeof()/sizeof(char32_t)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как это исправить?

Никак не пофиксить. Искать библиотеку для работы с юникодом.

Еще можно посчитать длину руками - посчитать количество байт, для которых выполняется `(byte & 0b11000000) != 0b10000000`. Если в строке валидный UTF-8, то получится число [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) в строке. Это обычно равно числу символов, но в каких-то хитрых случаях несколько code points могут кодировать один символ.

Comment: Если определена константа `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, то wchar_t это UCS (UCS-4), правда под Windows, ЕМНИП, wchar_t это UTF-16, но может ключ какой появился с тех пор. Да, с точки зрения количества знакомест, конечно важны, и нормализация, и композитные символы, и символы нулевой и двойной ширины... Но, на практике, количество символов Unicode с точки зрения обработки или хранения получается стандартными средствами C++20, либо `std::wstring(L"привет мир!").size()`, либо `sizeof(U"привет мир!")/sizeof(U"") - 1`.

Comment: @Serge3leo На практике строка вряд ли будет в литерале, скорее будет загружаться откуда-то. Можно, конечно, использовать `std::codecvt`, как подсказали в комментариях, но обходить байты руками выглядит быстрее.

Comment: Скажем, для работы в Unicode (в UCS, а не в UTF-8), кроме `std::wstring` имеются `std:wcout`, `std:wcin` и т.п., которые не требуют явных преобразований туда-сюда.